# Did the Axis use Villa Cisneros during WW2 for contact with South America?

Tags: world-war-two, spain, argentina

I have read that a German U-boat refueling at Villa Cisneros was attacked and sunk. I have also read that After Germany Invaded Russia in 1941 a Japanese technical mission returning to Japan was flown to Rio de Janiro via Vila Cisneros on the Atlantic coast. According to a book The "Nazi Menace" in Argentina, 1931-1947 By Ronald C. Newton, A German General was flown to Argentina to organise former crew members of the Graff Spee who escaped captivity in Uruguay into building an airstrip at Cordoba for receiving long range flights from Germany.

Prior to WW2 and up until Brazil joined the Alliance against Germany in 1943, vila Cisneros was a regular waypoint for trans-Atlantic flights by the Italian airline LATI.

Please can anybody enlarge upon this issue and provide any sources for further reading?

What role did Vila Cisneros play in the later half of WW2?

[LATI carried mail](http://transatlanticmailbyair.wordpress.com/category/lati/)

Answer (score 5):

The link you offer right up front says LATI ceased operations to South America in December 1941:

"*LATI (Linee Aeree Transcontinentali Italiane) LATI began service to South America in December 1939 and ceased operations in December 1941*."

Actually LATI was banned from operating by the Brazilians on 27 December 1941.

Also, one might note that in July 1941 the USN was operating out of the port of Recife and by mid-1943 was operating patrol aircraft from a naval air station at Ibura Field near Recife.  Probably would have cramped LATI's operations after the Italians declared war on the US. Additional bases were at Santa Cruz, Sao Luis, and Parnamirim, so access from the east was fairly well covered.  See: http://www.sixtant.net/2011/index.php, also http://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USN/Admin-Hist/146-SouthAtlantic/146-SoLant-Chron.html